# Visual studio 2012 cannot drag and drop controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, devexpress

In my visual studio ultimate 2012 version working in windows 10
Iam trying to drag and drop any control from toolbox to form designer sends me an error :

"the operation could not be completed the system cannot find the file specified "
And also even any toolbox like Button or EditText I cannot move them inside the Form. With mouse movement the move only with keyboard arrows inside the Form.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, it seems that you are developing a Winforms project.

It is recommended that you follow the steps below to try to fix it:

1. Run Visual Studio as administrator
2. Delete the .vs of the project and rebuild the project
3. You can upgrade Visual Studio to the latest version. If it still doesn’t work, you can use the Visual Studio installation tool to repair Visual Studio

If the above operations do not work, you can open the Event Viewer that comes with Windows to view Windows Logs to find out the specific reason